# How to get Shape Name in office 365 office.Interop.word

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-interop

How can I get the exact picture name from `word.Document.Shape.Name` method. I tried that but it is not getting the exact name. I tried like

```
objWord.Document.getItem(activeWord).Shape.getItem(index).Name
```

But it won't get the exact name. Is there any other method to return the Logo name in a document?. Should `InlineShape` serve the above functionality?.

Please suggest how can I retrieve the Logo name inside a Word document. I'm using Word 2016.

Comment: I use to copy content from one document and paste to another document.Everything pasting fine but the image name is not properly displaying when I try to access through Shape.Name. I used to do the given code.objword.document.get_Item(activedocname).ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory().objword.document.get_Item(activedocname).ActiveWindow.Selection.Delete().objword.document.get_Item(activedocname).ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste(). Everything fine but the Shape.Name return Picture 1 insted of actual picture name.

Comment: Now click the EDIT link under your Question and add this information to the text in the question so that the question makes sense, please...

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you report - losing the Shape.Name when copying/pasting between documents - is to be expected. Since this is a Shape, use the `Shape.AlternativeText` property to store the information currently in the Shape.Name. That will come across intact.